# Management web service for WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Does [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) support web services for system management?

I want to develop a desktop program to connect to ESB server and do the administration tasks without using web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already existing services in side the ESB which is also used by the admin GUI.

Step 1: Make admin services WSDL visible by editing carbon XML ({ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/carbon.xml)

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

Step 2: See which services available for you to use by starting ESB with osgiConsole

```
sh {ESB_HOME}/bin/wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole
```

Step 3:  See the list of services ( you can type this in ESB command window, just type enter you will get osgi command mode )

```
osgi> listAdminServices
```

you can see sample java client login to ESB and listing user roles in below link, just refer this for your service implementation. Basically first need to login to ESB before calling any admin service and use login cookie to call other services on next step.

http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/03/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html